# Issues connecting to a web service in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, wsdl

I am using a third party wsdl to connect to a service. I have been provided a security certificate and a username / password.

I have:

- Installed the certificate on my Windows 7 machine
- Ensured it has the correct permissions
- Have the correct location for the API stored in the web.config

The code fails each time. The error messages change, but they include:

- Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
- An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
- Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

This is the code I am executing:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

//Third party client
var client = new ConnectionPortClient();

//Including these two lines or not does not affect the outcome
//client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
//client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";

client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\..\cert.p12", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

var results = client.getResults("");
```

And here is the relevant part of the web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="assessmentBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
            receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://endpoint/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="assessmentBinding" contract="API.Assessment"
          name="assessmentSOAP" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Any thoughts on what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

you use [Certificate message credential type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733098.aspx) but you are trying to set up UserName/Password for [UserName message credential type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731058.aspx) - this is wrong. check the article about [Message Security with a Certificate Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733098.aspx)

Comment: Even removing the two lines with the user name and password doesn't seem to make a difference (everything I try I try with and without those two lines just in case)